# How do I use the Typescript compiler API to do BOTH incremental and watch mode?

Tags: typescript

I have been able to create an incremental Typescript transpiler using a tsbuildinfo file using the sample code in the (still unmerged) PR https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-wiki/pull/225/files, specifically createIncrementalProgram.

Unfortunately, startup times to scan the file system for a moderately large project makes the compilation unnecessarily slow when used in "watch mode" for a MeteorJS-based app.

I don’t understand how to create a compiler program instance that can stick around and react to file system changes without needing to rescan. Does anyone know how to combine the different Typescript Compiler API objects to accomplish this? (host, program, CreateProgram etc).

The documentation here is quite terse.